# Problems pasting styled HTML tables into Microsoft Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word

Take this CSS / HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">
/* Column widths */
.columnTime {
    width: 7%;
}
.columnTheme1Class {
    width: 66%;
}
.columnTheme2Classes {
    width: 54%;
}
.columnTheme3Classes {
    width: 42%;
}
.columnPosition {
    width: 10%;
}
.columnName {
    width: 17%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
/* This is the default font for all cells */font-family: Calibri;
}
table tbody tr:hover td {
    color: #000;
    background: #efefef;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: #666;
}
.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.containerMeeting {
    margin-bottom: 3mm;
}
.cellBibleReading {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right-style: none;
}
.cellNotes {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: italic;
}
.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}
.cellTheme {
    border-right-style: none;
}
.cellPosition {
    color: gray;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
.borderHEADINGOuter {
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.borderHEADINGInner {
    border-bottom: 4px gray solid;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.tableHEADING {
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.tableHEADING td {
    border: none;
}
.textSpecialEvent {
    text-align: center;
}
.textSpecialEventLocation {
    text-align: center;
}
.tableDATE {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.tableTFGW {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #606a70;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletTFGW {
    /*padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;*/
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #606a70; /*font-size: 14pt;*/;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.tableAYFM {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletAYFM {
    /*padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;*/
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #c18626; /*font-size: 14pt;*/;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textDuplicate {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.textMaterial {
    /* Uncomment to hide the material */
    /* display:none;*/
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.textMethod {
    /* Uncomment to hide the method */
    /* display:none;*/
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.textStudyNumberReference {
}
.textSongTitle {
    /* Uncomment to hide the song title */
    /* display:none;*/
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.cellClass {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: gray;
}
.tableLAC {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #961526;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletLAC {
    /*padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;*/
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #961526; /*font-size: 14pt;*/;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textDuration {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textTheme {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongLabel {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongNumber {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textCongregation {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.textTitle {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.tableWeekend {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellWEEKEND {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textWEEKEND {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #8b8378;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cellWEEKENDText {
    padding-left: 3mm;
}
.textPTSLabel {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.textPTSValue {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
/* For right-to-left: text directions swapped */
[dir=rtl] .textCongregation {
    text-align: right;
}
[dir=rtl] .textTitle {
    text-align: left;
}
[dir=rtl] .cellPosition {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
}
[dir=rtl] .floatRight {
    float: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
}
@media print {
body {
    background: #FFF;
}
.containerPage, .containerMeeting, .tableDATE, .tableHEADING, .tableTFGW, .tableAYFM, .tableLAC, .tableWeekend {
    width: 99%;
    min-width: 99%;
    max-width: 99%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
}
</style>
<title>Keynsham Midweek Meeting Schedule</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <div class="borderHEADINGOuter">
            <div class="borderHEADINGInner">
                <table class="tableHEADING">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="textCongregation">Keynsham</td>
                        <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a name="week0" />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableDATE">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnPosition" /><col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="3">
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Chairman:</div>
                May 4-10 | GENESIS 36-37</td>
                <td class="cellName">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Host:<br />
                    Co-host:</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">2a<br />
                2b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
                <td class="cellTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">114</span>
                <span class="textSongTitle">“Exercise Patience”</span> </td>
                <td class="cellPosition">Prayer:</td>
                <td class="cellName">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:21</td>
                <td class="cellTheme" colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(1 min.) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableTFGW">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnPosition" /><col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="3">
                <div class="textTFGW">
                    TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:31</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">“Joseph Becomes a Victim of Jealousy”</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span>
                <span class="textMethod">Talk</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span>
                <span class="textMethod">Questions and Answers</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
                <td class="cellTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span>
                <span class="textMaterial">Ge 36:1-19<span class="textStudyNumberReference"> 
                (th study 5)</span> </span></td>
                <td class="cellPosition">Student:</td>
                <td class="cellName">6</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnPosition" /><col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="3">
                <div class="textAYFM">
                    APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY</div>
                </td>
                <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:57</td>
                <td class="cellTheme" colspan="2"><span class="bulletAYFM">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme"></span><span class="textTheme">Apply Yourself 
                to Reading and Teaching</span> <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)
                </span><span class="textMaterial">Understandable to Others<span class="textStudyNumberReference"> 
                (th study 17)</span> </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:02</td>
                <td class="cellTheme"><span class="bulletAYFM">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Talk</span> <span class="textDuration">(5 
                min. or less) </span><span class="textMaterial">w02 10/15 30-31​—Theme: 
                Why Should Christians Have Godly Jealousy?<span class="textStudyNumberReference"> 
                (th study 6)</span> </span></td>
                <td class="cellPosition">Student:</td>
                <td class="cellName">7</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableLAC">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnPosition" /><col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellLAC" colspan="4">
                <div class="textLAC">
                    LIVING AS CHRISTIANS</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:07</td>
                <td class="" colspan="3"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">126</span>
                <span class="textSongTitle">Stay Awake, Stand Firm, Grow Mighty</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:22</td>
                <td class="cellTheme" colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">“Are You Prepared?”</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(15 min.) </span>
                <span class="textMethod">Discussion with Video</span> </td>
                <td class="cellName">8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:52</td>
                <td class="cellTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Congregation Bible Study</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(30 min.) </span>
                <span class="textMaterial">jy chap. 113</span> </td>
                <td class="cellPosition">Conductor:<br />
                Reader:</td>
                <td class="cellName">9<br />
                10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">20:55</td>
                <td class="cellTheme" colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textTheme">Concluding Comments</span>
                <span class="textDuration">(3 min. or less) </span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">21:00</td>
                <td class="cellTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
                <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
                <span class="textSongNumber">84</span>
                <span class="textSongTitle">Reaching Out</span> </td>
                <td class="cellPosition">Prayer:</td>
                <td class="cellName">11</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is what it looks like in a browser:

[image: Browser]

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1m6yg9c/). As far as I am aware there is nothing wrong with this HTML / CSS structurally.

Yet, if I select the content and paste it into Microsoft Word 2016:

[image: Word]

The columns are not consistent. Why is this?

## Update

I also noticed the Time column on the left is inconsistent.

In each of my `table` objects I was using a `colgroup`:

```
<table class="tableTFGW" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="columnTime" />
    <col class="columnTheme1Class" />
    <col class="columnPosition" />
    <col class="columnName" />
  </colgroup>
```

What I thought I was try was duplicate the `width` properties from the above classes into each of my cell classes, like this:

```
.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
    width:7%;
}
.cellTheme {
    border-right-style: none;
}
.cellPosition {
    color: gray;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    width:10%;
}
.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    width:17%;
}
```

This is improved:

[image: Word 2]

- The right hand column is all good.
- Most of the left hand column is good (just not the very top)

So it seems that Word does not obey the `colgroup` object when establishing the styling of the table cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word's formatting is based on XML, not HTML or CSS. Pasted tables are translated to Word format and Word's default setting "Automatically resize to fit contents" is applied.

For a more consistent appearance in Word and HTML, create the tables in Word and export as HTML. The HTML will be bloated with additional Word formatting code, but the appearance will be much more similar in Word and in a browser.

Comment: This is not an option. My software uses XML / XSL to transform the content into HTMl which is then displayed in a internal web browser control. But the user is permitted to copy the content and past it to Word. As you will see from my updated question a key factor here is that Word ignores the `colgroup` styling and does not apply it. Moving this   information into the actual cells resolves 95% of the issues.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, pasted tables from non-Word sources have the "Automatically resize to fit contents" property applied. That causes Word to ignore your preset column widths.

Comment: It is mostly resolved by applying the width styles to the cells themselves. Then it pastes pretty much OK. It is clearly bugged because it ignores the styles as defined via `colgroup`. Thanks for your answer but it is not a solution for my circumstances.

Comment: Having a different idea than Microsoft about how a program should operate is not a bug. Word is designed to operate this way, there is no operational defect in what you describe. I'm glad you found a workaround. If you would like to suggest that Microsoft change this behavior, please post your idea at https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application

Comment: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/40343413-pasting-in-html-tables-should-not-ignore-the-colgr

Answer (score 1):

MS Word understands HTML `width`, but not CSS widths. Try e.g.

```html
<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1>
<tr><td width=100>...</td>
 <td width=200>...</td>
 <td width=300>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note: you cannot use percentage in HTML width, only integer number in pixels.